# Change contentType dynamically in JQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, pdf

Is it possible to dynamically change the contentType using JQuery/AJAX?

For example:

```
$("li").click(function(){
   $("#pdfDiv").hide();
       $.getJSON("IndexServlet", {id: this.id,"EVENT":"GETPDF"}, function(data){
            var url1 = 'data:application/pdf;base64' + data;
            var setContent = $.ajax({
                     contentType:"application/pdf"
            });                     
   setContent.done(function(){
     $("#pdfDiv").append(url1).show();
   });
});
```

The reason for this is because I am retrieving JSON data through the response but I want to somehow use the JSON data(which is the 64 bit string of a PDF) and display a PDF to the page.

Answer (score 0):

No, by the time the data has been passed to the completion function of `getJSON()`, the content type has already been interpreted and the data parsed according to that type.  The content type needs to either be returned with the data or set appropriately before you make your ajax call or you'd have to hook into jQuery's ajax infrastructure to participate in guessing what the content type should be.

If you want to interpret the same data yourself in two different ways, you will have to select a content type that does no parsing (like a string) and then parse it yourself both ways.

Comment: How would I go about returning the content type with the data?

Comment: @ChandlerE. - on your server, you would set the content type header in your response to the Ajax request.